# Sublime incorrectly highlighting php heredoc blocks as syntax error

Tags: php, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, heredoc

So this isn't supposed to be happening:

[image]

That's a properly formatted heredoc, but it looks like Submlime sees`<<<HTML` as an unterminated `<html>` tag. Does anyone else have this issue? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum post](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5879), this is a bug in the TextMate language bundle, and the problem can fixed by either upgrading that bundle, or moving to ST3 (which appears to contain the newer bundle). e.g.,

ST3:

[image: Sublime Text 3 in PHP Highlighting Mode]

vs ST2:

[image: Sublime Text 2 in PHP Highlighting Mode]

Comment: sublime 2. I'll take a look into updating the syntax definition file - thanks! I tried to search this up a bunch but I think the terms are too close to other issues and I kept coming up with other people's solutions to unrelated problems.